# Is BID installed as part of SQL Server of Visual Studio or either?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bids

Does Busienss Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), part of the Visual Studio IDE, come with both SQL Serevr 2008 R2 Developers Edition and also as part of Visual Studio 2008 Developer's Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIDS is included with SQL Server. It is not part of the regular Visual Studio install. You can get BIDS by installing just the client tools from SQL Server without having to do a full install of the product.